# pika exception connection closed local host python

Tags: python, rabbitmq

Following is the error. It was working fine 1 day ago. But when I am trying to run it again it's giving me following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/nor-devops/projects/nor_7sm_denaliml/denali/back_testing_agent_python_consumer.py", line 22, in <module>

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost')) 
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 339, in __init__
 self._process_io_for_connection_setup()
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 374, in _process_io_for_connection_setup
self._open_error_result.is_ready)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 395, in _flush_output
raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

Code is as follows:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='init_filtering')

channel.basic_consume(callback,
                      queue='init_filtering',
                      no_ack=True)

print(' [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C')

channel.start_consuming()
```

My RabbitMQ is running and use my project is on local machine. pika version is 0.10.0

Comment: Hi! It would be interesting to see RabbitMQ logs as well.